# Wordpress: widget title's width not the same as sidebar title

Tags: html, css, wordpress, widget, sidebar

the widget title's width of a Wordpress theme I'm making is slightly shorter than the sidebar title.

[widget title image](http://postimg.org/image/crtcy5llp/)

This is the functions.php coding:

```
    if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
    register_sidebar(array(
       'before_widget' => '<div class="text-content">',
       'after_widget' => '</div></div>',
       'before_title' => '<div id="text"><h2 class="text-title">',
       'after_title' => '</h2>',
       'name' => '1'
    ));
```

And this is the php and .css coding I'm using for both widget titles and custom sidebar titles

```css
#sidebar
{
 background: url(./images/sidebar-image.png) no-repeat center top;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 512px 0 0 0!important;
 float: left;
 width: 32%;
 max-width: 32%;
 height: auto;
}

#sidebar #text
{
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
width: 92%;
}

#sidebar, #sidebar .text-content
{
margin: 0 0 20px 0;
padding: 15px;
font: 400 12px Roboto, Helvetica, sans-serif;
text-align: justify;
}

#sidebar H2.text-title
{
 background: #00CBAC;
 border: 0;
 border-radius: 5px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 5px;
 font: 700 16px Bitter, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-align: center;
 letter-spacing: -1px;
 text-transform: uppercase;

}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
<?php if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar(1) ) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<div id="text">
<h2 class="text-title">Title</h2>
<div class="text-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I'd love the widget title to have the same width of the sidebar title, but I don't know how to proceed without messing things up.

Thank you!

Edit: [test link](http://gwyneth-paltrow.org/test/)

Edit 2: Thank you **Mia Marks**, you were actually right! I slighly changed the function.php coding and is now working:

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
register_sidebar(array(
   'before_widget' => '',
   'after_widget' => '</div></div>',
   'before_title' => '<div id="text"><h2 class="text-title">',
   'after_title' => '</h2><div class="text-content">',
   'name' => '1'
));
```

Comment: Provide the to the real problem so that one can debug it.

Comment: its seems it takes different class name, can u paste sidebar output html code here or realtime link to the page  so that we can help you out

Comment: looks like it's getting nested by other stuff - like maybe it's already inside a text-content div - so inspect the output in your source code or code inspector in the browser developer tools and see what the actual html output is to adjust your before/after widget/title stuff.